# Synchronizing cloud services with FTP

Tags: ftp, google-drive, mega

I have several cloud services, all of which I want to be able to access easily. I finally came to the solution of an FTP server.

The cloud services that I use are

- [MEGA](https://mega.co.nz)
- [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com)
- [Degoo](https://degoo.com/)

I would like to create an FTP server that basically stores and synchronizes file metadata  with the cloud providers listed above, e.g. Folder "GDrive" has the file metadata synchronized with my Google drive account, but the files aren't actually stored on the server. (This is what OneDrive used to do before the update)

When the client requests something, e.g. "GDrive/abc.txt", the FTP server downloads the file from google drive and then sends it to the client. This way, the only thing taking up storage on the ftp server is the metadata for all of my files.

Is this possible for any/all of the above cloud services?

Comment: So storing the files from Google drive/onedrive on the ftp server is out of the question?

Comment: @Matthew No, the point here is not to synchronize the files themselves, but the metadata and only have the server download the actual files when needed. (and then delete them so as not to take up space).